# How can i start a link in Tor browser using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to open a link in `"tor"` using python. I just want to execute the code and it should start to visit that web page.

I haven't tried anything yet because I am new to this field of python. I know only the basics so kindly tolerate me.

Comment: what do you mean by `"tor"` – please help us answer your question with a clear demonstration of the difficulty you're facing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Selenium module for tor browser.

**Installation**

> pip install tbselenium

**Basic usage**

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
with TorBrowserDriver("/path/to/TorBrowserBundle/") as driver:
driver.get('https://check.torproject.org')
```

**Note:** TorBrowserDriver does not download Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) for you. You should download, extract TBB and provide its path when you initialize TorBrowserDriver.

Reference: [Check](https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium)